# vue.js Import and load component dynamically

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to get the following code dynamically import a component from a folder. However, vue doesn't import anything or show an error. (It's as if it doesn't sense the computed  field changing).

What am I doing wrong? (I have already gone through the forums and this seems rare)

```js
<template>
  <component v-bind:is="column"></component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Column",
  computed: {
    column() { 
      return () => import(`../columns/${this.$store.state.column}.vue`);
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to import/register all components, you can either do this on component level like below or globally.

```js
export default {
   components: {
     ColumnA: () => import('../columns/ColumnA'),
     ColumnB: () => import('../columns/ColumnB'),
     ColumnC: () => import('../columns/ColumnC'),
     ColumnD: () => import('../columns/ColumnD'),
   }
}
```

Next you have to make sure you can map your state to `column-a` to match the component name. if that's the case you can just use:

```js
computed: {
   column() {
      return this.$store.state.column;
   }
}
```

If not you would have to create a map:

```js
computed: {
   column() {
      const mappedComponents = {
         myStateKeyForColumnA: 'column-a',
         myStateKeyForColumnB: 'column-b',
         myStateKeyForColumnC: 'column-c',
         myStateKeyForColumnD: 'column-d',
      }
      return mappedComponents[this.$store.state.column];
   }
}
```

**Edit**
To register the components globally one can use [`require.context`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/).

**in main.js**

```js
const context = require.context('./path/to/columns', true, /\.vue$/)

for (const key of context.keys()) {
  // key gives us the file name, ie. ./ColumnA.vue
  // the code below, to register the component name is based on the above patterh
  // likely you will have to modify this
  Vue.component(key.slice(2).split('.')[0], () => context(key))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but typing the components out manually in components: defeats the purpose of importing dynamically

Comment: Well, you will always have to register them in the "vue" framework. Otherwise it won't work. You can register the components globally though.

Comment: @hitwill provided an example with require.context. Be carefull to adjust the logic to strip of the component name based on the path